# Logging Python function to log.html like robot keywords

Tags: python, robotframework

#### Python Code

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.api import logger    

def decorator():
    ....
    do something
    ....

class Tester(object):
    @keyword
    def run_hello(self):
        self.hello()

    @decorator
    def hello(self):
        logger.info("hello word")
```

#### Robot Code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Test.py 

*** Test Cases ***
Run Hello
    Run Hello
```

When the robot run keyword `run_hello`,the python function `hello()` can logging to log.html like robot user keyword? How to write the `decorator` function?

And I want the log.html like the image:

[image: log.html images]

Comment: If your question is "should the `print` from `hello()`" turn up in the generated log.html, the answer is yes, it must be there. Does something different happen when you run your code through robotframework, thus your question? As for the decorator, how to create one is a totally different topic; the main question there is - what do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: Sorry, the description is not clear enough. I update it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. And my python code

```
from functools import wraps
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import register_run_keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def robot_run_keyword(func):
@wraps(func)
def func_wrapper(self,*args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(func, "second"):
        setattr(func, "second", True)
        ar = list(args)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            ar.append("%s=%s"%(key,value))
        register_run_keyword("WiseLibrary",func.__name__,len(ar),deprecation_warning=False)
        return BuiltIn().run_keyword(func.__name__, *ar)
    else:
        delattr(func, "second")
        return func(self,*args, **kwargs)
return func_wrapper
```